# Laravel Eloquent Many to Many Relationship pivot table

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have three tables  `categories`, `film_categories` and `films`  and three models respectively `Category`, `FilmCategory` and `Film`.

I have seen many tutorials where they don't create a `pivot table model` like i have created `FilmCategory` Model . They just create a pivot table `film_categories` without a model.

My question is what is the best practise - ?

Should i create a `FilmCategory` model and set a `hasMany` relationship

```
class Film extends Model
 {
     use HasFactory;

    protected $primaryKey = 'film_id';

    /**
     * Film film Relationship 
     * 
     * @return Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
     */
    public function categories()
    {
        return  $this->hasMany(FilmCategory::class, 'film_id', 'film_id');
    }

}
```

**OR**

Should i just create a pivot table `film_categories` without a model `FilmCategory` and set `belongsToMany` relationship

```
class Film extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $primaryKey = 'film_id';

    /**
     * Film film Relationship 
     * 
     * @return Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
     */
    public function categoriesWithPivot()
    {
        return  $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'film_categories', 'film_id', 'category_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: create belongsToMany .no need to use pivot model

Answer (score 1):

Technically speaking, both option are fine. You can implement the two of them, and depends on what you want to implement/achieve in the logic part of the code, use one between the two that suits best. Here are things to consider:

First, depends on what is `film_categories` table used for. If the table is simply exists to relate `films` and `categories` tables using many-to-many relationship, then there's no need to create the `FilmCategory` model, and you can just use `belongsToMany()`. Otherwise, if the `film_categories` will relates to another table, then you should create `FilmCategory` model and define the relation using `hasMany()`. You're also likely need to add a primary-key field to `film_categories` if this is the case.

The second consideration to take is what kind of data structure you want to have. Using the codes that you provide, you can get `Film`s using these 2 queries and it'll gives you the correct values but with different structures:

```php
Film::with('categoriesWithPivot')->get();
// Each record will have `Film`, `Category`, and its pivot of `film_categories` table

// OR

// Assuming that `FilmCategory` model has `belongsTo` relation to `Category` ...
Film::with('categories', 'categories.category')->get();
// Will gives you the same content-values as the above, but with in a different structure
```

And that's it. The first point is mostly more important to consider than the second. But the choice is completely yours. I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes i think there is no harm creating a FilmCategory model.  I can create both two type of relationship and may use in future it its require.

Comment: If you find the answer to be most useful, please don't forget to mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

Since the film_categories table does not represent an entity in your system, I think you should define a belongsToMany relationship and should not create a separate model for the pivot table. If You still wanna have a model for your pivot table so create a model that extends Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot class. Check documentation here: [model for pivot table](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models)